# Establishing the connection between MongoDB with PowerBI via BI connector and ODBC using docker pod

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, powerbi, odbc, mongodb-biconnector

I’m currently working on a data that involves connecting MongoDB to a BI tool using the MongoDB BI Connector and the MongoDB ODBC Driver. I'm having a huge amount of database instance (MongoDB Compass) and it is taking long time to load in PowerBI by using BI connector of Mongosqld.exe, So I created the Bi connector as POD in the hosted server OpenShift and it is successfully running up. But the problem is when I'm trying to connect it with ODBC Driver it is getting failed.

[Here is the screenshot of the error I'm getting:]https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1azT.png

And I'm expecting it should be connected successful.
Are tell me is there any other way to connect it successfully?